# PHP array_merge not working

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Working with PHP.
I have array 1 with this keys and values:

```
$array_1 = array(
(more values)
'propub_cost_max' => 5,
'propub_cost_min' => 0.5,
'average_calc_last' => '-1 Months',
'propub_qtd_first_offer' => 4
);
```

and array 2:

```
$array_2 = array(
'propub_cost_max' => 20,
'propub_cost_min' => (no value),
'average_calc_last' => (no value),
'propub_qtd_first_offer' => (no value)
);
```

I want to merge array 2 with array 1 so i did:

```
$result = array_merge($array_2, $array_1);
```

But the result is:

```
$result = array(
(more values)
'propub_cost_max' => 5,
'propub_cost_min' => 0.5,
'average_calc_last' => '-1 Months',
'propub_qtd_first_offer' => 4
);
```

The propub_cost_max key should assume the value 20, right?

The idea is to maintain some values, and replace where the values are different if there is any value, of course.
I thought that array_merge should work, but...

Thank you all.

Comment: You have a `}` instead of a parenthesis.

Comment: "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one." http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php. in your case array_1 is the latter

Comment: Thank you @TheValyreanGroup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.". in your case array_1 is
>   the latter.

Says [nogad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6763587/nogad).

(link to [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) )

And also

> You have a } instead of a parenthesis.

As says [TheValyreanGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287472/thevalyreangroup).

Both of these are absolutely correct. So

```
$result = array_merge($array_1, $array_2);
```

Will solve your problem. Values are swapped so that `$array_2` will now overwrite the values in `$array_1`.

To solve your overall issue of wanting to update *some* values, without knowing which values and which conditions you want to preserve, we're reduced to simply not overwriting values with empty ones, so :

```
$array_2 = array_filter($array_2); //clears empty values
$result = array_merge($array_1, $array_2); // as before. updates non-empty new values.
```

Comment: The `}` is obviously a copying error, otherwise the script wouldn't even run and he wouldn't get any result at all.

Comment: Well it will solve the problem in this test case, but the desired behavior in the general case is presumably that max gets the larger of the 2 values, not the second of the two (even though swapping them here helps).

Comment: @Barmar well yes, but I think it's still worth pointing that comment out as typos are often critical in causing errors and a user with a habit of typos (and of not spotting and correcting them) will have lotsof code issues they can't solve themselves.

Comment: seeing as how I generate an answer from other peoples comment I've communitied it, so feel free to edit as you need, @JeremyKahan

Comment: @Martin that is very sporting of you, but I do not know PHP well enough to code it element-wise so if the key contains min one chooses the smaller of the 2 values (assuming both exist), if it contains max, choose the larger, and otherwise punt.

Comment: I have added `array_filter` so that empty values do not overwrite non-empty values, aside from that we'd need further details from OP to do more.

Comment: @Martin thank you very much. Sorry about the } . Great answer, works great.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
array_merge_recursive($array_1, $array_2);
```

Comment: Good job. So why does this work? What is the difference ?

Comment: `array_merge` replaces the new old value with the new value if there is a match between key names. but `array_merge_recursive` puts them inside one big array together.

Comment: See this for more information
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php